# What does model.evaluate output?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I was running my gated recurrent unit (GRU) model. An after ti was over I had

```
score = model15.evaluate(X20_test, y20_test)
print('Score: {}'.format(score))
```

and the output was.

`[0.030501108373429363, 0.00272163194425038]`

Here is my code for my model:

```
model20 = Sequential()
model20.add(GRU(units=70, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(1,12),activity_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.0001)))
model20.add(GRU(units=50, return_sequences=True,dropout=0.1))
model20.add(GRU(units=30, dropout=0.1))
model20.add(Dense(units=5))
model20.add(Dense(units=3))
model20.add(Dense(units=1, activation='relu'))
model20.compile(loss=['mae'], optimizer=Adam(lr=0.0001),metrics=['mse']) 
model20.summary() 


history20=model20.fit(X20_train, y20_train, batch_size=1000,epochs=25,validation_split=0.1, verbose=1, callbacks=[TensorBoardColabCallback(tbc),Early_Stop])
```

Is the first number the `loss` MAE number for the test data using the model, and the second is the `metrics` MSE number for the data data using the model. If so, does this mean lower is better?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Optimizing for a metric (here MAE) and assessing for a different one (here MSE) does not make much sense in such regression settings. The `metric` argument is not necessarily used in regression problems (like this one), where frequently the loss and the metric are one and the same thing; that means, if at the end of the day you care for MSE performance, you should optimize for MSE (not MAE), and vice versa.

Comment: But I've read online that using MAE are your loss function is sometimes better as it is more prone to outliers in the dataset. When I used MSE as my loss function I got worse results than when I used MAE as my loss function.

Comment: What exactly is "results" here? MSE (your metric)? You mean, optimizing for MAE gave you a better MSE than optimizing directly for MSE?

Comment: Yes, when I used MAE as my loss instead of  MSE, and used MSE as my metrics to see how it preforms, I found out that gave me better results than using MSE as my loss.

Comment: OK, you should stick with this setting then (shouldn't happen according to the theory, but the experiment is the ultimate judge).

Comment: Just in case, I'm running the code again with MSE as the loss to double check, I'll let you know how it goes once it is done.

Comment: @desertnaut I just ran it and i have almost identical results even the measurement vs predict graph is almost exactly the same. So now I could put MAE in my metricrs to measure MAE as well?

Comment: You are already measuring MAE in `loss`; you can also specify more than one metrics, e.g. `metrics=['mse', 'mae']`, in the same run. In general, we don't use `metrics` in regression problems - we just use the loss as a metric.

Comment: No I did what you said eariler and I put `loss=['mse']` instead of `mae` and my resultrs were almost the same if not silightly better. This means I can use `metrics=['mae']` to measure both mse and mae.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first number is the loss, `mae`, for the test data using the model. The second is the metrics. A smaller `mae` is always better.

Comment: So a smaller MAE and MSE is always better, but for example If I chose accuracy as my metrics higher would be better.
Sorry in your opinion what is considered a high MAE or MSE number?

Comment: It depends on the data. A MSE of 1000 when you predict the price of houses is very small. When you predict a person's height in centimeters, not so much!

Comment: I'm trying to predit power which ranges anywhere between 0 to 6000 W, does this mean my MSE is low for my given data? I do know you can't give me an answer as you didn't see the dataframe

Comment: 0.002 on 6000 is crazy low. that's basically perfection. there must be a mistake

Comment: No values range from 0 to 6000, not necessailry at 6000. I will post a figure of measured vs predicted, to get a better look at it.

Comment: Does MSE and MAE graphs indicate that there is something wrong?

Comment: That seems very very good. If you put both on the same scale you'll see it's almost perfect predictions

Comment: That is great! I thought since the validation loss was mostly under( but extremly close) to  the trianing loss that this is an underfitting case, but I read eariler that is not always true? At the end though the training loss went under the validation loss. ( Note: the same scale you mean the toggle y-axis log scale button)